# setTimeout callback is not being called in UNIT TESTS even after using fakeTimer and runAllTimers

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I can't figure out why the callback passed to setTimeout is not called in my unit tests even after using **jest.runAllTimers**. The useEffect is called but the timeout callbacks aren't called and not covered as per Istanbul code coverage report as well.

The implementation is somewhat like this:

React Component:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(5);
    useEffect(() => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('***** Timer Ran!!! *********');
            if(timer <= 5 && timer > 0) setTimer(timer - 1);
            else {
                return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }, [timer]);

    <>
        // some JSX
    </>
};
```

Test:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers(); // at top of file

it('should run code inside useEffect', () => {
    const startBtn = screen.getByTestId('start-btn');
    expect(startBtn).toBeEnabled();
    // more code
    jest.runAllTimers();
});
```

Note: I have tried wrapping `jest.runAllTimers` in waitFor and act and it doesn't work.

Comment: What test result did you get?  And what's the version of jest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved when I wrapped the rendering of the component with `act`.

Sample code:

```js
...
jest.useFakeTimers(); 
...

describe('Test Component', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      render(<MyComponent />);
    });

    await act(async () => {
      jest.runAllTimers();
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should check if ...', async () => {
    // tests
  });
});
```